# How to override the entire product page with a new template for products which are Out of Stock?

Tags: magento2, product, theme, frontend, magento2.3.1

I would like to change the way Magento 2's product page looks for products which are Out of Stock. Basically I want to replace the entire product page with a simple message (and maybe a picture of the product).

In Magento 1, this could be done easily because a single template (`catalog/product/view.phtml`) rendered the entire product page, and you could simply add some code at the top of that template to check if the product was Out of Stock and display a message instead of the normal product page.

However, in Magento 2, there is no equivalent of `catalog/product/view.phtml` (that I can see) and the whole product page is rendered via layout XML.

So how can I accomplish this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Layout Handle to update the current layout.

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View">
        <plugin name="outofstock_layout" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Helper\Product\View"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Helper/Product/View.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Helper\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;

class View
{
    /**
     * @var StockItemRepository
     */
    protected $stockItemRepository;

    /**
     * View constructor.
     *
     * @param StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
    ) {
        $this->stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $subject
     * @param Page $resultPage
     * @param Product $product
     * @param $params
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeInitProductLayout(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $subject ,$resultPage, $product, $params){
        try {
            $productStock = $this->stockItemRepository->get($product->getId());
            if (!$productStock->getIsInStock()) {
                $resultPage->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_product_view_outofstock');
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $noSuchEntityException) {
            // Do no thing
        }

        return [$resultPage, $product, $params];
    }
}
```

Here is the new Layout handle for out of stock:

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_outofstock.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```